# getitem() is not returning the called Fragment in my ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have added 8 Fragments to my adapter **ViewPagerAdapter** in a ArrayList using **MainActivity** class. Here is my Code:

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> mFragmentList) {
    super(fm);
    this.mFragmentList =mFragmentList ;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
  }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

//Method for adding Fragment
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolBar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
public static final String MYTAG = "mytag";
private int[] tabIcons = {R.drawable.parkingicon, R.drawable.childrenparkicon, R.drawable.cafeteriaicon,
        R.drawable.teaicon, R.drawable.stationaryicon, R.drawable.securityicons, R.drawable.tumtumicon,
        R.drawable.wastebinicon};

static final LatLng ZOOM = new LatLng(19.129, 72.915);
public static GoogleMap googleMap;
private static Context mContext;
//Context context= getApplicationContext();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();

    //ToolBar Initialisation
    toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //ViewPager Intialisation
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    //TabLAyout Initialisation
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    Log.d("Tag", "i am before iconing");
    setupTabIcons();
    Log.d("Tag", "i am after iconing");

    try {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ZOOM, 15));
        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ZOOM).title("MYCheck Marker"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("Tag", "i am after google map calling");
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        Log.d("Tag", "i called tab at "+i);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabIcons[i]);
    }
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Log.d("Tag", "i am  goring to call ViewpagerAdapter");
    //Calling the Adapter Here
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Parking(), "Parkings");
    adapter.addFragment(new ChildrenPark(), "Children Parks");
    adapter.addFragment(new Cafeteria(), "Cafeteria");
    adapter.addFragment(new Canteens(), "Canteens");
    adapter.addFragment(new Stationary(), "Stationery");
    adapter.addFragment(new SecurityCheck(), "Security");
    adapter.addFragment(new TumTum(), "Tum Tum");
    adapter.addFragment(new WasteBins(), "WasteBins");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d("Tag", "i had set the Adapter for you and now moving out after adding all adapters. END");
}

public Context getContext(){
    return mContext;
}
```

}

So, i want to click on tab and add the corresponding fragment in Viewpager.But whenever i click first tab at postion 0, it is loading fragment at position 1. I am not able to know why my *getitem()* method of Adapter is not working properly. Please help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

change your `getItem()` to below, increase `position` by one.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
  }
```

and change your setupTabIcons' to `tabIcons.length`

```
 private void setupTabIcons() {
        for (int i = 0; i > tabIcons.length; i++) {
            Log.d("Tag", "i called tab at "+i);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabIcons[i]);
        }
    }
```

I have tested your code it should work for you.

Comment: I understand that +1 or  -1 can do the wonder, but it is not. Whwnever App loads it loads fragment of position 1 and not of 0 and on other hand when i click last tab to load last fragment, it loads nothing.  Anyway, thanks for reply.

Comment: one more problem is there in your setupTabIcons make size to 7, as you have only 8 Fragments

Comment: @shisharam i have 7 fragments and hence i ran my for loop from 0 to 8, its giving me proper results and if i make it to 7, last tab icon is not coming. Any other solution please ?

Comment: have You tried like above? I have edited answer.@vivek

Comment: try updating your both methods and check.

Comment: For fragment code, if i will make it to **position+1**, it will load 3rd fragment and for **for loop** code, if i make it to _i > 7_ it will go for infinite loop and hence will not set any icons... These both things are happening as expected. you can see to my raw code here

Comment: For fragment code, if i will make it to **position+1**, it will load 3rd fragment and for **for loop** code, if i make it to _i > 7_ it will go for infinite loop and hence will not set any icons... These both things are happening as expected. you can see to my raw code here : [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxvAsvUuvW6daU9sMVY0djA4LXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100934/discussion-between-shishram-and-vivek).

Comment: @vivek I have edited answer, Check now. hope it helps you now.

Comment: Have you found any solution for the problem that is happening... ?